# How to do logical replication on cascading standby server on postgres?

Tags: postgresql, debezium, logical-replication, logical-decoding

Is it possible to enable logical replication on standby server which is in cascading replication mode?

Comment: No, because you have to create a publication on the master: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-publication.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According `Debezium connector for PostgreSQL` [docs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html):

> As of release 12, PostgreSQL allows logical replication slots *only on primary servers*. This means that you can point a Debezium PostgreSQL connector to only the active primary server of a database cluster. Also, replication slots themselves are not propagated to replicas. If the primary server goes down, a new primary must be promoted.

> **Note.**
> There are discussions in the PostgreSQL community around a feature called `failover slots` that would help mitigate this problem, but as of PostgreSQL 12, they have not been implemented.

This feature is not implemented for the latest PostgreSQL release 13.

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html

Comment: As I learned at FOSDEM the other day, there's a pending [patch set](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/32/2968/) for adding support for streaming off stand-bys. So perhaps we may see this in PG 14.